Excel: Search for strings while excluding others within individual cells
I am hoping for help.  I am doing a veterinary pathology study on a large group of cases.  I want to check a group of cells on a row separately for inclusion of a string.  For the most part it's working, but in many rows it is not picking up on strings that it should.  I have tried different formulas to no avail.
I am using, as an example, =IF((COUNT(SEARCH({"fat atrophy,""inanition","serous atrophy of fat","negative energy balance","emaciation"},$E:$3))>0),"Y","N") to include all code words for nutritional disease
Check each cell in group for presence of one or more in array

To kick it up a notch, I also want to be able to add exclusionary criteria.  In the example above, I'd like to exclude cells that have a specific string (for example, I'd like to have two columns, one for "granuloma (no bacteria mentioned)" and "granuloma (bacteria mentioned)".  B6 would go in the latter, so I would want to exclude the mention of "bacteria" in the first column.
I do enter as an array formula with CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER, but this does not seem to help.  Is there another formula that can do what I want? I've tried a few others.  Or will I need to do special coding for this?
Thanks,
Lauren.
REVISED QUESTION
I am still having difficulty with this task and was advised to edit my original question for more clarification. Thanks for your continued help and interest @nkalvi!
I am hoping to search individual cells in Excel for one OR more strings in a list (inclusion criteria), while possibly excluding one OR more strings in a separate list.
I would love to have a BYROW/LAMBDA option since I have over 6000 rows of data.
Here is my very first ever attempt at using Markdown Tables generator, so please forgive me if I did it in error.
EXAMPLE 1
Output "Y" for bacterial colitis or enteritis.  Inclusion criteria (D2 OR D3) AND E4.  No exclusion criteria in this example.



BIRD
DIAGNOSIS1
DIAGNOSIS2
LIST1
LIST2
DESIRED OUTPUT




Bird1
Unknown enteritis
Dermatitis
enteritis
fungal
N


Bird2
Colitis

colitis
mycotic
N


Bird3
Enteritis
Fungal dermatitis

bacterial
N


Bird4
Dermatitis



N


Bird5
Fungal enteritis



N


Bird6

Bacterial colitis


Y



EXAMPLE 2
Output "Y" for no stated cause for enteritis or colitis, meaning there was no stated fungal/mycotic or bacterial cause.  Inclusion criteria (D2 OR D3).  Exclusion criteria (E2, E3, OR E4).



BIRD
DIAGNOSIS1
DIAGNOSIS2
LIST1
LIST2
DESIRED OUTPUT




Bird1
Unknown enteritis
Dermatitis
enteritis
fungal
Y


Bird2
Colitis

colitis
mycotic
Y


Bird3
Enteritis
Fungal dermatitis

bacterial
Y


Bird4
Dermatitis



N


Bird5
Fungal enteritis



N


Bird6

Bacterial colitis


N



Hope that helps and I am so grateful for any and all help!  I really want this to work!
Lauren.

Welcome to SO. It would help to help you if you provide your data as text within your question - best by using Markdown Table Generator. Furthermore you should also provide your expected output. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should be able to adapt my answer here to your problem.

Thank you!  This was my first post to StackOverflow, and so I greatly appreciate your help, kindness, and understanding.  As suggested, I went ahead and tried your suggestion with =IF((SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($$:$$,{"string"}))>0),"Y","N") and permutations of this to include and exclude strings that that works nearly perfectly!  THANK YOU!  I was getting SO frustrated!

I have had amazing help from nkalvi, and thank you so much Rob Rosenfeld!  However, I am still having problems.  With the suggestion from nkalvi (=IF(BYROW(data-set,LAMBDA(row,(COUNTIF(row,inclusion))))*(--NOT(BYROW(data_set,LAMBDA(row,OR(COUNTIF(row,exclusion)))))),"Y","N")), if an excluded text shows up in any other column in the data set, then a "N" will be returned.  I want to check each cell in a data set on a row for inclusion criteria and exclusion criteria.  Even better if I can use the BYROW feature but not absolutely necessary.

If you have Microsoft 365, you could try this:
Define tables for your lists to make it easier manage and use in formulas  (create these in an empty area or new sheet with an empty column between them)



Inclusion_list1
Inclusion_list1
Exclusion_list2




fat  atrophy
*granuloma*
*bacteria*


inanition
* to match cells containing the term



serous  atrophy of fat




negative  energy balance




emaciation





Define names to make the formulas easy manage



Name
Refers To




Data_area
=Sheet1!$D$3:$I$12 (to match all the cells with data)


is_in_list
=LAMRBDA(array,list,SUM(COUNTIF(array,list)))


data_in_list
=LAMBDA(list,  BYROW(Data_area,LAMBDA(row,is_in_list(row,list))))


is_in_exclusion_list2
=data_in_list(Exclusion_list2)


is_in_inclusion_list1
=data_in_list(Inclusion_list1)


is_in_inclusion_list2
=data_in_list(Inclusion_list2)


yes_no
=LAMBDA(if_true,IF(if_true,"Y","N"))



Since we have defined the Data_area we can use dynamic array formulas to get your details (first clear the contents in NUTRITIONAL); enter the following in the first row:



NUTRITIONAL
granuloma (no  bacteria mentioned)
granuloma (bacteria mentioned)






=yes_no(is_in_inclusion_list1)
=yes_no(is_in_inclusion_list2*(--NOT(is_in_exclusion_list2)))
=yes_no(is_in_inclusion_list2*is_in_exclusion_list2)
RHABDOMYOLYSIS
EMACIATION



Here's the result using your sample:



NUTRITIONAL
granuloma (no  bacteria mentioned)
granuloma  (bacteria mentioned)










Y
N
N
RHABDOMYOLYSIS
EMACIATION
EUTHANASIA





N
N
N
EXTERNAL TRAUMA
RUPTURED OVARIAN  FOLLICLE
PULMONARY  HEMORRHAGE
INTESTINAL NEMATODIASIS




N
N
N
NECROTIZING  OSTEOMYELITIS OF THE HEAD
PULMONARY SHOCK
HYPOXIA





Y
N
N
SHOCK
FAT ATROPHY
FUNGAL  VENTRICULITIS
CRYPTOSPORIDIOSIS
MESENTERITIS
HYPOXIA


N
N
Y
ORAL GRANULOMA WITH BACTERIA







N
N
N
BLOOD  CONTAMINATION
CYTOLOGY






N
N
N
MARKED  HEMOSIDEROSIS
LIVER






Y
N
N
FUNGAL  VENTRICULITIS
PULMONARY THROMBUS
PULMONARY SHOCK
MULTIFOCAL  NECROTIZING HEPATITIS
INANITION



Y
N
N
SYSTEMIC  LYMPHONODULAR HYPERPLASIA
NEPHRITIS
ENTERITIS
BILIARY  HYPERPLASIA AND PORTAL HEPATITIS
VASCULAR  CONGESTION IN THE BRAIN
FAT ATROPHY


Y
N
N
PULMONARY SHOCK
INANITION
ENTEROCOLITIS
PORTAL HEPATITIS
MYOCARDITIS




Update
2024-05-09
Following does not use any named functions; but uses named area and tables. You can replace these names (Data_area, Inclusion_list1 etc.) with ranges if you want.
Enter the following in first cell of these columns (clear all content in the column before entering):
NUTRITIONAL
=IF(BYROW(Data_area,LAMBDA(row,OR(COUNTIF(row,Inclusion_list1)))),"Y","N")

granuloma (no bacteria  mentioned)
=IF(BYROW(Data_area,LAMBDA(row,OR(COUNTIF(row,Inclusion_list2))))*(--NOT(BYROW(Data_area,LAMBDA(row,OR(COUNTIF(row,Exclusion_list2)))))),"Y","N")

granuloma (bacteria mentioned)
=IF(BYROW(Data_area,LAMBDA(row,SUM(COUNTIF(row,Inclusion_list2))))*      BYROW(Data_area,LAMBDA(row,SUM(COUNTIF(row,Exclusion_list2)))),"Y","N")


Update 2024-06-16



Variable/Function





item_count_in_list
Use wildcard match of COUNTIF to count how many terms from a list are found in diagnosis columns. Use TRIM(list) if spaces, especially at the beginning or end, in terms affect the output.


include_row
Use OR to include the row in match if ANY of the cells match the criteria



For checking items in lists A and B:
=LAMBDA(data_area, list_a, list_b,
    LET(
        item_count_in_list, LAMBDA(item, list,
            SUM(COUNTIF(item, "*" & list & "*"))
        ),
        in_a_and_b, LAMBDA(cell,
            AND(
                item_count_in_list(cell, list_a) > 0,
                item_count_in_list(cell, list_b) > 0
            )
        ),
        include_row, LAMBDA(row,
            OR(MAP(row, LAMBDA(cell, in_a_and_b(cell))))
        ),
        BYROW(
            data_area,
            LAMBDA(row, IF(include_row(row), "Y", "N"))
        )
    )
)(B2:C7, D2:D3, E4)

For checking items in A but not in B:
=LAMBDA(data_area, list_a, list_b,
    LET(
        item_count_in_list, LAMBDA(item, list,
            SUM(COUNTIF(item, "*" & list & "*"))
        ),
        in_a_not_b, LAMBDA(cell,
            AND(
                item_count_in_list(cell, list_a) > 0,
                item_count_in_list(cell, list_b) = 0
            )
        ),
        include_row, LAMBDA(row,
            OR(MAP(row, LAMBDA(cell, in_a_not_b(cell))))
        ),
        BYROW(
            data_area,
            LAMBDA(row, IF(include_row(row), "Y", "N"))
        )
    )
)(B2:C7, D2:D3, E2:E4)

Enter the formulas in the top cells of the output area as shown in the screenshots.



Update 2024-06-18
We could define criteria with the conditions needed. TRIM is used to strip extraneous spaces in the lists.
=LAMBDA(data_area, list_a, list_b, list_c,
    LET(
        in_list, LAMBDA(item, list,
            SUM(COUNTIF(item, "*" & list & "*"))
        ),
        criteria, LAMBDA(cell,
            AND(
                in_list(cell, list_a),
                in_list(cell, list_b),
                NOT(in_list(cell, list_c))
            )
        ),
        include_row, LAMBDA(row,
            OR(MAP(row, LAMBDA(cell, criteria(cell))))
        ),
        BYROW(data_area, LAMBDA(row, IF(include_row(row), "Y", "N")))
    )
)(
    B2:C7,
    "dermatitis",
    TEXTSPLIT(TRIM("bacteri or septic or sepsis"), " or "),
    TEXTSPLIT(TRIM("fungal or mycotic"), " or ")
)


Wow!  Thanks!  I am trying this, but I am finding a stumbling block about what to put for =LAMRBDA(array,list,SUM(COUNTIF(array,list))) and   =LAMBDA(list,BYROW(Data_area,LAMBDA(row,is_in_list(row,list)))).   Mostly, what do I put for "array" and "list" for the first, and what is "row" for the second. I tried to look this up in other Stack Overflow threads but I could not find the answers I was looking for. I realize I am a novice when it comes to complex formulas, but this looks really promising and I am incredibly appreciative of your help.

Hi Lauren, these are entered in the Name Manager or Define Name... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4. Only the formulas above the table needs to entered in the sheet.

Sigh, I am new to all this and it just isn't working for me. I defined a table, no problem.  I seem to be having trouble with the defining of names and I've read the links you sent.  But this does look like a very promising solution!

Hi Lauren, which version of Excel are you using?

Hi Lauren, please try with the updated suggest above - I have replaced the user defined functions.

My version of Excel is Microsoft 365.  Windows 11.  Thanks @nkalvi!

Good. Please give the updated solution above a try. I assume you've created all tables and added a name for the data area. Let me know if you need detailed steps.

@ nkalvi - That WORKED!!!  WOW!  That is this most PERFECT solution!  Incredible, thank you so much!!  You are so amazing and kind to have helped!  I really love your solution the best because I have 6700 cases in my table and I might want to change the inclusion and exclusion criteria as I go along.  It will be SO MUCH easier for me to modify the inclusion/exclusion tables rather than every line in the table of 6700 cases.  THANKS AGAIN!  I don't know if there is anything else I can do to express my gratitude!!!  - Lauren.

Happy to hear it! - and thanks for the question :)

I am having trouble again.  I can't include two cells on adjacent rows or columns in my inclusion data.  Sigh. I can't seem to include (or exclude) more than one term.

Sorry to hear it. That was a quickly put together solution. Let me take another look to see how to make it more flexible. Also using wildcards, especially '*' could be helpful. https://exceljet.net/glossary/wildcard It could be helpful if you could post a screenshot or provide more detailed example of the issue.

Hi @LaurenP, it looks like how SUM works seems to have changed with an update  for Office update for Mac. It works slightly differently under Windows :( Anyway, I have updated the 3 formulas above. On my Mac, changing the one for NUTRITIONAL to =IF(BYROW(Data_area,LAMBDA(row,OR(COUNTIF(row,Inclusion_list1)))),"Y","N") seems to have restored the functionality. Please try and let me know.

Hi @nkalvi - Oh my goodness you are a COMPLETE genius! I changed the "SUM" to "OR and it is now working perfectly again! All the cells in the column are populated again with a "Y" or an "N" and the formulas are interpreting the data correctly! I AM SO GRATEFUL! I was in tears! I couldn't understand why your solution was working perfectly and then didn't work at all, just days later. I thought I had done something wrong, like the format of the cell, etc etc. I was in despair about my research project.  You are so brilliant, I am amazed you discovered a solution to the solution so quickly!!!

Hi @nkalvi - I do have a related question. Is there a related "AND" to the "OR?" Say, if I wanted a "Y" if a patient had (atherosclerosis OR arteriosclerosis) AND cerebral ? Thanks beyond words, I wish there was a bigger way I could say thanks!!!!

Hi @nkalvi - Is there a way to do an AND where I am looking for "pulmonary" AND "shock" in the same data area cell?  So I would get a "Y" for "pulmonary shock" OR "shock, pulmonary" ?  If I use an OR as above, then I will get a "Y" for the cell if it has EITHER "pulmonary" OR "shock" but not both, and I have looked and tried but have not found a way to do this.  I think with BYROW and LAMBDA it gets so confusing for me! THANKS AGAIN!

And yes, I have been using the "*" wildcard on each side of each character string of interest (eg. atherosclerosis).  I'll see if I can get a screen shot.

I think I may have figured it out!  For AND,  =IF(BYROW(Data_area,LAMBDA(row,(COUNTIFS(row,Inclusion_list1,row,Inclusion_list2)))),"Y","N").  Seems to be working so far...

Happy to hear it!

I am having a problem with excluding data, can you help me?  In one column, for unknown inflammation, I want to include certain strings (eg. "colitis" or "enteritis") while excluding others (eg. "fungal" or "bacteri", etc.  My formula is =IF(BYROW(data_area,LAMBDA(row,OR(COUNTIF(row,Tables!C98:D98))))*(--NOT(BYROW(data_area1,LAMBDA(row,OR(COUNTIF(row,Tables!Q98:V98)))))),"Y","N") where Tables!C98 is enteritis etc and Tables!Q98:V98 are the exclusionary strings such as fungal.  If I use this formula, then “chronic enterocolitis” displays as “N” (wrong).  What am I doing wrong?

Sorry, I think I've figured this out.  It has to do with strings in other columns in data_set.  Sorry to bother again!

I am so sorry to be a pest, but I do think this is not working well.  With the formula =IF(BYROW(data_area,LAMBDA(row,OR(COUNTIF(row,Tables!C98:D98))))*(--NOT(BYROW(data_area1,LAMBDA(row,OR(COUNTIF(row,Tables!Q98:V98)))))),"Y","N"), if string is mentioned in another column it will return a "N".  For example, if one column in a row has "enteritis" and the other columns in the data_area are blank, it will return a "Y".  But if another column in the data_area says, say "fungal dermatitis" then it will return a "N".  If I delete the "fungal" it will return a "Y".  It's not linked to the same cell.

Would an "ISERROR" function help here?

No bother at all. Let me take a look at it.

Hey, you're right, it does not compare on cell basis within a row. I'll update the solution shortly.

Please make a backup before testing :)

I am so grateful for your willingness to keep working with me!  I make a back up every day of the data file, and any time I work on formula experiments, I always save a shortened version.  There are 6561 cases in my data set!  But I shorten to 200 in my experimental spreadsheets since this smaller set includes my concerns about inclusion/exclusion and is much smaller so Excel is quicker and doesn't crash.  Sadly, the new formula with MAP and CELL isn't working.  Nothing but "N" is returned.  Is "OR a requirement in this new formula?  Lauren.

This is so frustrating!  Thank you for your kindness and patience.  I've been trying to work on permutations of your formula and nothing is working.  As you know, I simply want to search (Y/N) on a cell-by-cell basis if a column in a row (cell) contains any items from the inclusionary list AND does NOT include any of the items from the exclusionary list.  I thought this might be simple but clearly it is not.  Please continue to work with me if you can!

I see the "OR" is required when including a group of cells for inclusionary or exclusionary data.  Sorry.  =IF(BYROW(data_area,LAMBDA(cell,OR(COUNTIF(Inclusion_list)))),"Y","N") works to include all inclusionary data in the inclusion_list.  Yay!  So "CELL" works!  But I need to find a way to exclude exclusionary data from the exclusion_list

The two options for including items from exclusion list, is checked by COUNTIF(cell, Exclusion_list2) = 0) for not including and COUNTIF(cell, Exclusion_list2) > 0) for including. If you could give me small sample of from your current data set, I could post a detailed example. OR and AND are required :)

Thanks!  How can I send you a small sample from the current data set?

Could you try to edit your (original) question to add it?

I have edited my original question to add two examples.  I really hope that helps!  Thank you for your patience and continued help.  I'm learning so much working with you!  I hope we find a great solution!

I'll look at it today.

This worked beautifully in the data set!  I know comments are not intended for thanks, but thanks!  I don't know how else to thank you other than to say that your formulas appear to work perfectly for the problem at hand.

Glad to hear it!

For bacterial dermatitis, I would need to have as inclusion data "dermatitis" AND (either bacteri or septic or sepsis) AND NOT (fungal or mycotic).  This would be more than a simple "OR" in an inclusion list.  Could you help me with this?

Please try the update - we could specify the lists in this manner too.

That works well too!  I greatly appreciate your help.  I am working on a stumbling block right now and I am not sure why it's not working.  I am searching for HYPERPLASIA to exclude BILIARY, but it's not working.  It's still including "biliary hyperplasia" I have tried your previous "For checking items in A but not in B" solution and this most recently solution but neither works.  Perhaps because there is only on inclusion requirement (hyperplasia) and one exclusion requirement (biliary), unlike with the previous lists or groups of text strings?  Thanks again, sorry to keep bothering!

No bother at all! You could try with the following pattern adopting the recent one: (B2:C7, "HYPERPLASIA", "", "BILIARY"). Basically the first two lists are for inclusion and the third one is for exclusion. For single values, just enter them within double quotes; for lists, use the TEXTSPLIT variant. Since we are matching with wildcard *, an empty string "" matches everything. Please let me know whether this helps.

Oh my goodness, your brilliance continues to impress me.  That worked, yet again! THANK YOU!

Glad to hear it!

Oh dear, it seems not to be working?  Perhaps I misinterpreted the output previously?.  All instances of "biliary hyperplasia" diagnosis are still being included when I want them excluded from this column about (hyperplasia apart from biliary hyperplasia). I used the new formula you posted on 6/18 and I changed the last 4 lines of text as you had suggested.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Sigh.  I feel like such a pest!

Please forgive me.  I've checked all occurrences of "BILIARY HYPERPLASIA" and "HYPERPLASIA" excluding "BILIARY" and it seems there is only one occurrence of where "BILIARY HYPERPLASIA" is still being included.  I don't know why this is for this one cell, but for all the other 35 cases it's working great!  My apologies!

No problem at all. If the cell that is being included is at either end of the data range, I would double check the range. Otherwise, double the check spaces in the condition. Here's an update to the in_list to trim spaces in the list SUM(COUNTIF(item, "*" & TRIM(list) & "*")). For example, "BILIARY " and "BILIARY" look the same in a list, but will not match the same way. If you're still having that cell included, please post a comment with the data in the cell verbatim within quotes.

For some reason, this cell corrected itself.  Yay!  I streamlined your formulas and double checked them all (about 150 columns total in the spreadsheet) and they are working perfectly.  This is wonderful, you saved the project!  Thank you so much!  If you are interested and willing, I would love to acknowledge your help in the manuscript we will submit to the journal for publication.  If you are interested, you can email me at exotics@carolinavet.com.  Thanks again!

Very happy to hear it - it's been a pleasure working on this :)
